# Center a certain character in recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I am working in an app where I have a recycle view to show input words from a user.

I want it to look like

```
       word1 - word2
longer word1 - word3
```

but I get

```
    word1 - word2
longer word1 - word3.
```

I have tried to put three textviews and use them in the recycle view, but no success so far. Maybe one could count the characters in the word pairs and append spaces at the end so that both words are equally big. But that feels like a bad solution.

Any ideas?

I have tried both `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, when I use `LinearLayout` the result is as above. When I use `RelativeLayout` only the last two words are shown. Nothing can be seen in the first `TextView`.

Here are the xml-files and java code

The textviews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/adapter_textview2"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/adapter_textview2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_root"
    tools:context="com.example.erikbylow.autoflash.TranslateActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linear_input"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/source_input"
                android:hint="Type text to translate"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/source_input"
                android:text="Translate"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="startTranslate"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/translate_recycle"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

From `CustomAdapter`

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
        Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set." + mDataSet.get(position).w1);
        viewHolder.getLeftTextView().setText(mDataSet.get(position).w1);
        viewHolder.getCenterTextView().setText(" - ");
        viewHolder.getRightTextView().setText( mDataSet.get(position).w2);

    }
```

EDIT:
Thanks for your help, how is how I got what I wanted by using `ADM:s` proposal and also adding `textAlignment`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview2"/>
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Align `TextView's` from right side .

```
 <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/adapter_textview2"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/adapter_textview3"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add `margins` and `padding` as per need .

If `Text` is unpredictable of any length you should rely on `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_textview3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i doubt `wrap_content` width of textView would allow him to achieve what he wants..

Comment: Text will be multiline if goes out of bound . `layout_weight` can be useful for long words .

Comment: Thank you for your help, by using linear layout and setting `textAlignment` properly I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I don't know why you have 3 text views when the example shows only 2 in a row.

I came up with this - changing the layout to a linear layout with a horizontal orientation and adding some weight so that the second text view stays in place.

Try it and tell me if it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adapter_textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="reallly loooong looooong text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adapter_textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/adapter_textview1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="22"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="long text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The third textview is for the dash " - ", the idea is to always have that in the center.